# Cross-platform pgrep in PHP

Tags: php, process

I have a PHP file that fires a process with one of the shell/shell_exec/passthru/system functions.
I need to be able to find if the process is stil running.

Is there any way to do it with the regular PHP tools? ( I mean no fork/posix extensions are available )

Answer (score 0):

Use [`proc_open()`](http://php.net/proc_open) + [`proc_get_status()`](http://php.net/proc_get_status) + [`proc_close()`](http://php.net/proc_close).

Comment: This will not solve my issue; I need to check a status after a while, to see if the process is still running. In this case I'd need to store the process id, which is not possible, since PHP will fire proc_close automatically when the current script ends.

Comment: What about DBMS / files / session then ? Could you save `pid` to somewhere, if not use `proc_close()` in same script ?

Comment: Even if I store the pid, what is the correct way to check for a process with that pid cross-platform?

Comment: @petermolnar with platform-dependent `php_uname()` + `switch` + `system()` (or analogue) with platform-dependent command. I see no other option (IMHO).